# who can I call to a httpget action method with jquery as a link

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

so Iam usin jtable and I need to add a column and in that column call want of my action that is in another controller to show a new view

for adding a column in jtable

```
TestColumn: {
                    title: 'IrRuta',
                    display: function (data) {
var foo = '<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/">Visit W3Schools</a>';
 return foo;
}
```

I need to do like that but it should call my action

```
[HttpGet]
      public ActionResult Index(int? id)
            {
             //todo
            }
```

i tried like this but didn't work

```
var foo = '@Html.ActionLink("ruta", "Index", "Ruta") ';
var foo = '@Url.Action("Index", "Ruta")';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this at the end

```
   IrRuta: {
                    title: 'IrRuta',
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    display: function (data) {
                        return '<a href="/RutaCliente/Index?clienteId=' + data.record.ClienteId + '"><span>irRuta</span></a>';
                    }
```